# Abrir form en la parte superior derecha de la pantalla independientemente de su tamaño

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un pequeño formulario de medidas Width 391 y Height 160, quiero que ese formulario cuando se ejecute salga en la parte superior derecha de la pantalla(esquina de la pantalla) esto sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla en la que se este ejecutando, tomando en cuenta que se puede ejecutar en pantallas de diferentes tamaños.

Como podria hacerlo?
NO tengo codigo de ejemplo ya que no se por donde empezar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892090/how-to-set-winform-start-position-at-top-right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usa el evento `Load` para cambiar la posición, es el primer momento donde podrás saber el tamaño real de la pantalla (tras aplicarse la configuración del usuario y la escala automática)

```
private void OnLoad (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Screen scr = Screen.FromPoint (Location);
   Location = new Point (scr.WorkingArea.Right - Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top);
}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7892320/5213794

Edit: Agrego una pequeña explicación basado en el comentario de [Alex Rivas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/62883/alex-rivas).

El constructor de `Point` recibe las coordenadas en `x` e `y` de donde se ubicará el punto (en el caso del ejemplo será el `Form`)

`Screen.WorkingArea` es una propiedad de tipo `Rectangle` que representa el tamaño de la pantalla completa.

Agregando a esto, `Rectangle` tiene las propiedades `Top` y `Right` que devuelven la coordenada más alta (y) y más a la derecha (x) del `Rectangle`.

De esta manera, nosotros podemos saber que el formulario debe estar, en el punto más alto, (`scr.WorkingArea.Top`) y que su ubicación sobre el eje `x` debe ser el punto más a la derecha (`scr.WorkingArea.Right`) menos el ancho del formulario mismo (`scr.WorkingArea.Right - Width`).

Espero que haya quedado claro!

Comment: scr.WorkingArea.Right - Width, scr.WorkingArea.Top que hace esto exactamente??

Comment: @AlexRivas ahí modifique la respuesta agregando una pequeña explicación, cualquier cosa decime!

Comment: ohhh muchas gracias por la explicacion sirvio de ayuda

Comment: y si quiero que cambie de tamaño el formulario en proporcion a la pantalla donde se ejecute, si es chica la pantalla que mantenga su tamaño el Form pero si mas grande que se haga mas grande el Form, si tengo idea de como hacerlo se me ocurre hacer un if y comparar el tamaño de la pantalla algo asi scr.WorkingArea.Width == 1920 y darle el tamaño de acuerdo a la resolucion de la pantalla, de que otra forma lo podria hacer?

Comment: Estaría bueno que hagas otra pregunta con ese planteo, ya que se desvía un poco de esta y es posible que no ayude a otros usuarios también!